# How to know if the differential equation have constant solutions when the function vanishes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose the following differential equation: $y'=2y+1$, i know that i can find the constant solutions using the fact that $y=c \iff y' =0, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

But when I use this, there are many cases when replacing by $y' = 0$(or some other higher derivative) the function $y$ is canceled, per example:

$y\cdot y'' = 0$

$y'' \cdot e^y=2$.

In general, $y$ will be canceled if its coefficient is one of its derivatives.

So, in these cases, how can I find the constant solutions?

Comment: Given the general differential problem $F(y^{(n)},\ldots,y'',y',y,t)=0$ you are asking if $F(0,\ldots,0,0,c,t)=0$ holds for all $t$. To me, it looks like indeed the possibilities are plenty and will depend on assumptions on $F$, e.g. $F$ is linear, etc. The two examples you provide already show this, the first one has an infinite number of solutions (even beyond $y=c$) while the second, as mentioned, has none. Do you have more info on the class of equations under consideration?

Comment: I already answer my own question, thanks @PepeToro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the function $y(x)$ is canceled by some derivative, then in the differential equation only constant values ​​and the independent variable will remain.

and it will depend only on whether the equation reduces to an identity. If reduces to identity then there are infinite constant solutions, otherwise there will be zero constant solutions.